# combining values from two sql query result rows into one for a datagrid in c#

Tags: c#, sql, pivot-table

I have a employee table which contains employee information and a Contact details table which contains the phone numbers of the employees. the employees have more than 2 phone numbers.

now, to display the employee information, i have a datagrid. what i want to do is display the first 2 numbers along with the employee information in the datagrid.

i use the following method to fill the data grid

```
    public static void SignUpControllerDay(DateTime Date, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView PassedGrid)
    {
        string sql_SignUp = String.Format(@"SELECT e.Emp_ID as Emp_ID,
                                      e.First_Name+ ' ' +e.Last_Name as Name,
                                      sum(o.Quantity) as Sum
                                      FROM Employee e,OT_hours o,Position p,Signup_Sheet s
                                      WHERE e.Emp_ID=o.Emp_ID
                                      and e.Emp_ID = s.Employee_ID
                                      and s.Day_Shift = 1
                                      and e.Position_ID = p.Position_ID
                                      and p.Position_Name = 'Controller'
                                      and o.Quantity NOT IN(0.3)
                                            and s.Date = '{0}'
                                      and o.Date <= CONVERT(VARCHAR,'{0}',101) AND o.Date > CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(YYYY,-1,'{0}'),101)
                                      GROUP BY e.Emp_ID,e.First_Name+' '+e.Last_Name,p.Position_Name
                                      ORDER BY Sum", Date);

        SqlConnection sqlConn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd_SignUp;
        SqlDataReader dr_SignUp;
        try
        {
            sqlConn = new SqlConnection(databaseConnectionString);
            sqlConn.Open();
            cmd_SignUp = new SqlCommand(sql_SignUp, sqlConn);
            dr_SignUp = cmd_SignUp.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr_SignUp.Read())
            {
                PassedGrid.Rows.Add(dr_SignUp["Emp_ID"].ToString(), dr_SignUp["Name"].ToString(), dr_SignUp["Sum"].ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error found in SignUpControllerDay..." + Environment.NewLine + e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sqlConn != null)
            {
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

the above method displays the empid,name,sum of the employees. all i want to do is display any 2 phone numbers from the contact_details table. i tried using a data reader to get the phone numbers based on the employee id, but it did not work.

please help....

Comment: Don't use string.Format() like that to insert your parameters.

Comment: And what did not work? Did you get any errors? What did you do to try your approach? More info would be nice!

Comment: i have a data grid with the following columns " empid, name, sum, phone1, phone2"
as the phone numbers are located in a different table, i dont know how to get them in the data grid. when i refrence the employee table with the phone num,ber table, then i get duplicate values in the result set.

only wuestion is, how do i display the first 2 phone numbers of the employee in the data grid

Comment: Re-tagged this to in SQL. Hopefully, that will get it the attention that it really needs. less of a C# question that one for SQL gurus.

Comment: I added pivot-table as a tag as this is what it really is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what reggie wants to do but before I give you any help reggie lets take a look at a couple of things that you may want to look at:

1. As mentioned **do not use String.Format or Dynamic SQL**, if you are on SQL Server make use of stored procedures with parameterized SQL Command objects
2. You are having the client (web app or windows app) doing too much work for something that is really data intensive (SQL work rather then C# work)
3. You do not need to loop at all or even use a datareader as it is just bloating your code and unnecessary
4. In your finally clause you close the connection but you never set your connection or the actual sql command object to null.  I know C# garbage collects but it is a good point of practice to do so.
5. SQL Server 2005 and up brings to us the `PIVOT` key word, look it up in **BOL**

In regards to your question if you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can use PIVOT.  Given that you mentioned there can be 2 contact numbers let us assume one is work and one is home.

You could do this:

```
SELECT 
      FullName, 
      [Work], 
      [Home] 
FROM
(SELECT 
       l.FullName, 
       p.PhoneType, 
       p.PhoneNumber 
 FROM 
       Login l 
 INNER JOIN 
       Phone p 
 ON p.LoginID = l.LoginID) ps
PIVOT
(
 MAX(ps.PhoneNumber)
FOR
 ps.PhoneType IN ([Home], [Work])
) AS pvt
```

Login is simply your Employees table and Phone is your contacts table with the phone number.  I assume an employee id can be found in the contacts table (that is Login.LoginID = Phone.LoginID) or in your case Employee.EmpID=Contacts.EmpID.

So this:

[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/6126/onetime.jpg](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/6126/onetime.jpg)

With a standard query not using pivot then becomes this...:

[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/7395/2time.jpg](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/7395/2time.jpg)

When using pivot.

Comment: It is **not** good practice to set objects to null.  That is holdover from the days of COM and can in rare cases actually be harmful in .Net.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - I don't agree with you in this case the connection to sql is closed, it is good practice to set it to null / nothing since it no longer can be used.  I know the GC will take care of it.  I'd love for you to enlighten me as to why this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't reference the contact_details table anywhere in the SQL. You need to join the Employee and contact_details tables to include the phone numbers.

Comment: i agree with you. i referenced the contact table and this is what i got.
222222 reggie dsouza 2.4 647 878 6565
222222 reggie dsouza 2.4 778 242 2125
65456 Adam Long 4.9 222 233 5789
65456 Adam Long 4.9 989 897 3456

even after grouping them according to the employee, i got this result. thus it gives out duplicate values. as in,the employee information is repeated based on the number. i wanna show the information in the data grid in this format" empid, name, toal, phone1, phone 2 "

any suggestionss

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you are asking for. This is tricky, and my gut instinct is that you'd need use a stored procedure to programmatically get the result that you want. i have re-tagged this as SQL, which is the real nature of the question, and I'd suggest editing your question to make it clearer that you are looking to get the two phone numbers in a single result.

Comment: @Adam. reggie - Use PIVOT, see my response below.  One employee, 2 phone numbers, returns one row with both numbers listed without any looping or any interface code.  Now in his C# app all he needs to do is gobble it up in a dataset and return it to the datagrid.